# The percentage of answered questions is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, statistics

I tend to look at the percentage of answered questions since we're always near the 90% threshold. There are 310 unsanwered questions right now, which is precisely 90% answered. Today, here's what I saw:

[image]
[image]

If such bug reports are useless, feel free to remove my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This came up on [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125117/incorrect-answer-rate-being-displayed) and a number of other sites. It seems to be an API glitch that affected all Stack Exchange site statistic ads. It should be fixed now.

> The bug is fixed, but the ad is cached for an hour...so it will take a bit for the fix to show up. *Nick Craver♦*

Looks like it will fix itself within about an hour.